# Twilio client error when accepting client calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I am using `twilio client` to make & accept calls from a browser. But when I run the accept page, I get a javascript error on the browser -

```
Uncaught Twilio.Exception: 401: Unable to determine account.
```

@ line - twilio.js:2683

Here's the code from my controlled thats gets executed when showing the accept call page/view -

```
def prepare_accept_call    
  # create the twilio capability object
  capability = Twilio::Util::Capability.new TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN

  # guessing this is not needed for accepting calls, but added to see if it fixes my issue and it doesnt :(
  capability.allow_client_outgoing TWILIO_APP_SID

  capability.allow_client_incoming "some-client-identifier"

  # use this token for client JS - Twilio.Device.setup("#{@token}");
  @token = capability.generate
end
```

NOTE -: I am successfully able to show the make call page, there are no javascript error - when i click the call button I get the flash microphone permission popup. There are no 401. So guessing my key, tokens etc are ok.

Any idea what could be happening here?

Comment: where are you specifying your accountsid and token when generating the token?

Comment: right here - Twilio::Util::Capability.new TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN

Comment: Have you confirmed that the TWILIO_APP_SID is correct?

Comment: yea its correct, like i said in my NOTE above, that the opposite workflow (make calls) works and I am using the same twilio keys for both the workflows.

Answer (score 7):

I also had this error with similar conditions where all my credentials were correct but the Twilio client debugger was spitting out "Application not found 31001" - which is a Twilio client error code by the way.  I realized that I had not entered the Voice request url that is in the applications section.  Apparently this is a necessary prerequisite to access the Twilio Client service.

I feel they should have been more clear with their message but regardless I solved it by entering a publicly reachable callback url using a SSH tunneler like [Localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) or free server like Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the code it should work, because it looks good. Can you verify where TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID and TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN are ultimately being defined? maybe that could have something to do with it?

Comment: i tried replacing the constants with literals values, still same issue.